# Installing bugzilla with mysql

Tags: mysql, bugzilla

I'm trying to install Bugzilla as part of setting up Testopia.  I'm using 3.6.3 because our company site uses that and there are no plans to upgrade in the foreseeable future.  I've install mysql but when I run the `/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DBD::mysql` script it fails.  The error message though isn't very descriptive.  I've included it below:

> Running Mkbootstrap for DBD::mysql ()
>   chmod 644 mysql.bs
>   rm -f blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so
>   LD_RUN_PATH="/home/y/lib/mysql:/lib64" /usr/bin/perl myld gcc  -shared -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic dbdimp.o mysql.o  -o blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so       \
>             -L/home/y/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient -lz -lcrypt -lnsl -lm -lssl -lcrypto       \
>
> /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/y/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so when searching for -lmysqlclient
>   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so] Error 1
>    CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.021.tar.gz
>    /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
>   Skipping test because of notest pragma
>   Running make install
>    Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible

I don't know why libmysqlclient.so is incompatible.  Is the installed version of mysql too old or is it too recent for this version of Bugzilla?  The error message does not specify.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this looks like this](https://serverfault.com/questions/132061/need-help-getting-perl-module-dbdmysql-installed-for-bugzilla-on-redhat) which suggest you update your operating system.

hope this could help